# unable to set a variable's value inside an if block in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

Can someone explain why the $URL variable in this code is always set to 'Location: unknown.php' by the time the header($URL) is called?:  If I comment out the declaration/initialization in the first line the code works, but I get a variable undeclared warning (I also get these warnings if I declare $URL before the if blocks without initializing it).

```
$URL = 'Location: unknown.php';
if ($spring){
    if (($leaves)&&(!$stem)&&(!$root)&&(!$head)&&(!$whole)){$URL = 'Location: snow-mold.php';}
} else if ($other) {
    if ((!$leaves)&&(!$stem)&&(!$root)&&($head)&&(!$whole)){$URL = 'Location: o01.php';}
    if (($whole) || ($root) ){$URL = 'Location: o02.php';}
    if (($leaves)&&($stem)&&(!$root)&&($head)&&(!$whole)){$URL = 'Location: o03.php';}
    if (($leaves)&&($stem)&&(!$root)&&(!$head)&&(!$whole)){$URL = 'Location: o04.php';}
    if ((!$leaves)&&($stem)&&(!$root)&&($head)&&(!$whole)){$URL = 'Location: o03.php';}
    if (($leaves)&&(!$stem)&&(!$root)&&($head)&&(!$whole)){$URL = 'Location: o05.php';}
    if ((!$leaves)&&($stem)&&(!$root)&&(!$head)&&(!$whole)){$URL = 'Location: o06.php';}
    if (($leaves)&&(!$stem)&&(!$root)&&(!$head)&&(!$whole)){$URL = 'Location: o07.php';}
}
header($URL);
```

Okay, I've simplified the code to highlight the problem...

```
$spring = (isset($_POST['season']) && strcmp($_POST['season'],'spring') == 0);
$URL = 'Location: unknown.php';
if ($spring){
    $URL = 'Location: snow-mold.php';
}
header($URL);
```

always redirects to unknown.php. If I change `$URL = 'Location: unknown.php'` to `$URL;`, the code redirects to snow-mold.php if and only if spring is selected, But I get a $URL undefined warning.

Comment: Because none of the conditionals is true, obviously. But unless you write them in a saner manner there's little hope of making sense of this.

Comment: for your own sake, try to come up with a bit clearer way to check those variables, or at least format it better

Comment: I just spent 3 minutes trying to clean that up but then my brain melted out my ear.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters - this is difficult to read/parse. If you can share the code that sets the `$leaves', `$stem`, etc. variables we may be able to help you find a cleaner approach.

Comment: Damn near Domain Style Language worthy.

Comment: Yeah, I know its hard to read... I'm porting some logic from a Perl script somebody else wrote.  What's weird to me is the conditionals are evaluating to true when they should be... if I comment out the $URL initialization, the logic works but I get an undeclared variable error.

Comment: And undeclared variable is `$URL`, right? Also, can you debug all these variables and show the results here?

Comment: @raina77ow , I've updated my post to be more clear... unfortunately I'm using a CMS that won't let me debug easily.  This is the error that I'm getting: `Notice: Undefined variable: URL in /cwis/aliases/wwwtest/agriculture/plantsci/winter_cereals/disease-expert-system/es.php on line 7`

Comment: After seeing your update, it looks like the easiest way to 'fix' (read: prevent redirection) is to use this line: `if (isset($url)) { header($url); }` instead of just `header($url);`

Comment: @raina77ow... nope, that doesn't work either. I'm really at a loss. I've rewritten everything ([link]http://pastebin.com/WmUcKEXL see the comments at the end)  I have no idea what is going on...

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can rewrite your code with series of `if-elsif` constructs - so your poor `leaves` won't be checked 7 times in that `$other` branch, for example.

But I'd suggest another approach: implementing a (sort of) hash function that takes all these tree parts as arguments (or, even better, a single associative array with these values as keys):

```
function happy_tree_hash($leaves, $stem, $root, $head, $whole) {
    // assuming each of this can be only TRUE or FALSE,
    // a bit mask should suffice:
    return (bool)$leaves << 4 
        | (bool)$stem << 3 
        | (bool)$root << 2 
        | (bool)$head << 1 
        | (bool)$whole;
}
```

... then assign value to your `$url` variable from a simple associative array:

```
$locations = array(
  5 => 'o02.php',  // whole and root
  16 => 'o07.php', // leaves only 
  ... 
);
...
$key = happy_tree_hash($leaves, $stem, $root, $head, $whole);
if (isset($locations[$key])) {
    $url = $locations[$key];
} else {
    $url = 'unknown.php'; 
}
header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: Granted the logic is hard to parse but why isn't the value of $URL being set in the if blocks when I initialize it beforehand? The value changes if I don't initialize, but then I get warnings.

Comment: I've seen references to bitwise operators before but never really understood how/why you would use them. This example is perfect!! Thanks Igor!